# How to calculate lengths with angles

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am coding a roof at a 45 degree angle. I can't seem to find the length I would need to make the roof symmetrical. What equation do I use to find the lengths of the roof?

This is the code:

```
penup()
speed(10)
setposition(-100,0)
pendown()
forward(200)
left(135)
forward(150)
left(90)
forward(150)
penup()
setposition(0,0)
```

And an image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFCzN.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3):

Ah, this is why we should pay attention in geometry.

You're describing a 45-90-45 triangle with a hypotenuse of 200.  The ratios in a 45-90-45 triangle are 1:sqrt(2):1.  So, your sides will be 200/sqrt(2) or 141.4.

Comment: Thank you. Is that the same for all angles, or just 90 degree ones?

Answer (score 0):

Doing the math is good, but there's usually a way in turtle to work around it:

```
from turtle import *

speed('fast')

setx(100)
goto(0, 100)
goto(-100, 0)
home()

done()
```